# How to remove the port from URL in Webpack Dev Server hot reload?

Tags: webpack, proxy, alias, webpack-dev-server, hot-reload

I'm running my app on localhost port 80 with an alias (I need this for php backend)
The frontend is running with VueJs + Webpack + Hot Module Reload on port 3000 using a proxy.

I setup my `webpack.config.js` and everything is fine, except that I can't figure out how to remove the `:3000` from the url.

If I open `http://my-alias` instead of `http://my-alias:3000` Hot Module Reload fails with

```
[HMR] Update failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
```

---

Here's an extract of my `webpack.config.js`:

```
module.exports = (env, argv) => {
    return {
        mode: env.NODE_ENV,
        watch: false,
        entry: {
            main: './src/main.js'
        },
        output: {
            path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'assets/javascripts'),
            publicPath: '/assets/javascripts/',
            filename: env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? '[name].min.js' : '[name].js'
        },
        devServer: {
            hot: true,
            open: false,
            publicPath: '/assets/javascripts/',
            contentBase: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'index.php')],
            watchContentBase: true,
            compress: true,
            port: 3000,
            host: 'my-alias',
            historyApiFallback: true,
            proxy: {
                '*': {
                    target: 'http://my-alias',
                    secure: false,
                    changeOrigin: true
                }
            },
            // ... etc
        },
```

Any idea?

Comment: I have the same problem but for a different reason. Did you manage to get any solution. It would work great for me if there was a way to just use the window.location host. My use case btw is that I'm accessing my dev server both through localhost and ngrok, and they use different ports.

Comment: How do you proxy to the app?

Comment: I'm running my app on localhost port 80 with an alias
The proxy target goes to the local port 80

Comment: It is kinda hard to tell without knowing how your backend works. Have you tried switching those ports around (backend is on port 3000 and webpack dev server on 80)? Logically (no matter what server you are on) you would need to run your main server on port 80 to get rid of it in the hostname.

Comment: did you manage to get this working? I have the exact same situation

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the public URL of your server.

```js
module.exports = (env, argv) => {
    return {
        ...
        devServer: {
            ...
            public: 'http://my-alias',
            ...
        },
```

https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverpublic

Comment: I already tried this but it doesn't help. Don't know if it's a webpack bug, or due to something in my config. Thanks anyway for trying to help

Comment: Actually I think it is due to your `proxy` config. The `proxy: { '*': { target: 'http://my-alias', ...` section tells webpack to send all requests hiting `http://my-alias:3000` from your browser to `http://my-alias`. Provided it is your PHP backend, indeed HMR fails with `Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0`, because it is getting some HTML from your PHP, rather than the expected JSON from webpack. You should not use proxy to redirect all requests (i.e. use `*`) to your backend. You only want to reidrect the requests for your backend api, e.g. `'/api'` instead of `'*'`.

Comment: Also if your backend is listening on `http://my-alias:80` you cannot expect to use your webpack dev server on `http://my-alias:80` too. You have to either use different hostname, different port or different both. So either leave backend on `http://my-alias:80` and access the webpack dev server on `http://my-alias:3000`, or you can run backend on `http://my-alias:80` and dev server on `http://my-second-alias:80`. The key is to not rely on the assumption in your app that backend and frontend share address. Create two constants or env variables for the FE and BE URLs, so they can be different.

Comment: Some details about my workflow and what I'm trying to do:

- My backend is running on a local PHP server on port 80. Its url is http://my-alias/admin/some-page

When I run webpack dev server I never go into the backend, which is a pure PHP admin.

Webpack is used only in Frontend, in a pure VueJS application.
I'm just trying to access the frontend urls at http://my-alias instead of http://my-alias:3000

There's nothing related to the backend, no php, but my alias is setup on port 80 on my localhost server. That's why I redirect the requests with the webpack proxy.

Comment: I got that part, I have similar setup. What I don't understand why do you run both the backend and frontend under the same `my-alias`? If your backend is listening on `my-alias:80`, than hot reload requests will hit your backend instead of the frontend dev server, and indeed the backend cannot serve the correct JSON, it returns an HTML or XML or similar, which starts with `<`, thus your error. Try running your frontend on `my-alias` and backend on `my-second-alias`. Webpack proxy and your backend both listaning in `my-alias:80` is a source of conflict.

Comment: The port is added to the public URL though.. causing sockjs to fail to open a ws connection to the dev server if it's already proxied for you.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it is a React app with a PHP backend, I didn't use alias, I just add the scripts names in my index.php and defined the root div (this is just for the dev config env).

```
<?php
// index.php at http://localhost/
?>
  <div id="root"></div>
  <script src="http://localhost:3000/">
  <script src="http://192.168.1.111:3000/static/js/bundle.js">
  <script src="http://192.168.1.111:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js">
  <script src="http://192.168.1.111:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js">
 //...
```

Add the CORS middleware in webpack to be able to load the js files from another domain (diffrent port).

```
const corsMiddleWare = (req, res, next) => {
 res.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', ['*']);
 res.append('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
 res.append('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
 next();
}
//...
before(app, server) {
//...
  app.use(corsMiddleWare);
//...
```

And `crossOriginLoading` and `publicPath` in the Webpack output config

```
 output: {
  /* your config */
  crossOriginLoading: 'anonymous',
  publicPath: 'http://localhost:3000/',
 }
```

With this config I am able to visit `http://localhost`, run the React app, and the hot reload works fine, in your case you can follow the same steps or update just the `publicPath`.